# How to get result in Laravel with where clause while passing model in controller method

Tags: laravel

I have a route to get a single post item by slug.

### Route

```
Route::get('post/{post}', 'PostController@details')->name('post.details');
```

While I want to pass the model in the controller method for the route.

### Controller

```
public function details(Post $post)
{
    // how to get the post by slug
}
```

> **My question** is how can I get the post by slug passing in the route
>   instead of post ID?

I am aware that I can pass the slug and get the post using where clause.

```
//Route
Route::get('post/{slug}', 'PostController@details')->name('post.details');

//Controller method
public function details($slug)
{
    $post = Post::with('slug', $slug)->first();
}
```

But I want to learn to do the same by passing the Model in the method.

Comment: Is there any reason behind not using id?

Comment: Post::with('slug', $slug)->first(); will always return the first entry in the posts table regardless of the slug. Is it intended or did you mean "where" instead of "with"? Please share the migration file for the posts table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set route key name to your model class

```php
//Post.php
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
```

This will inform Laravel injector/resolver to look the variable passed in `slug` column while fetching the object instance.

Comment: what are you getting with `$post` variable inside your controller? is it just a `slug` string or something else?

Comment: I am getting the `first` item in the row regardless `where` clause by `slug`

Comment: set your route as `Route::get('post/{post}', 'PostController@details')->name('post.details');` and controller method definition as `public function details(Post $post){}`

Comment: That is what exactly I have done. Let me try once again from scratch

Comment: that is how Laravel is fetching model object via Route binding. can you try doing `composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is [implicit route model binding](https://laravel-news.com/implicit-route-model-binding)

What you can do is in your Post model define `getRouteKeyName` like below

```
<?php

class Post extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the route key for the model.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'slug';
    }
}
```

and define your route like this:

```
Route::get('post/{post:slug}', 'PostController@details')->name('post.details');
```

and then in your controller

```
public function details(Post $post)
{
    // it will return post with slug name
    return $post;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for explaining it. One question. Will it return only a matching item? Sorry for the stupid question but new to Laravel and route is very confusing to me.

Comment: @CodeLover haven't tested but it believe it will return the first item